# Apollo graphql setting header to authmiddleware not working

Tags: react-native, async-await, apollo, apollo-client, asyncstorage

I am using react-native and apollo client and if I try to set header by jwt  stored in AsyncStorage, it seems not working. 
Other resolvers which doesn't need header works very well. My code is like below.

```js
import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-client";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import { ApolloLink } from "apollo-link";
import { createHttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";

const cache = new InMemoryCache();

const getToken = async () => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("jwt");

  if (token) {
    return token;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};

const httpLink = new createHttpLink({
  uri: ""
});

const authLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  operation.setContext({
    headers: {
      "X-JWT": getToken()
      // this is where I set headers by getToken function
      // If I change function getToken to real token in string type, it works then
    }
  });

  return forward(operation);
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: cache,
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink)
});

export default client;
```

Like I commented in the code, calling getToken function is not working what I expected. I think I should have more knowledge of async and await, but I don't get it what is the real problem.

The error message I get from console is `jwt malformed`. Please let me know how to fix this problem

Comment: An `async function` always returns a promise so you will get a pending promise. Can you try making the ApolloLink callback `async` and set `"X-JWT": await getToken()`

Comment: If I do like that, it gives me another error message `Network error: inner.subscribe is not a function`. @AsafAviv

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to use `setContext` directly

```js
import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-client";
import { createHttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";
import { setContext } from "apollo-link-context";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";

const httpLink = createHttpLink();

const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("jwt");

  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      "X-JWT": token || null
    }
  };
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

export default client;
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
    import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';
    
    // import getJwtToken // return string
    
    const authMiddleware = setContext(async (operation) =>{
        const token = await getJwtToken();
        return {
          headers: {
            authorization: token || null,
          },
        };
    });
    
    
    const link = ApolloLink.from([
      authMiddleware,
      // ...
      
    ]);
```

Comment: This answer helped me the most since I was chaining middleware with `from`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @аlex dykyі, this is my latest version

```js
    import { Auth } from "@aws-amplify/auth";
    import { ApolloClient, ApolloLink, createHttpLink, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";
    import { setContext } from "@apollo/client/link/context";
    
    export const getGraphqlClient = (url: string) => {
      const getToken = async () => {
        return (await Auth.currentSession()).getIdToken().getJwtToken();
      };
    
      const authMiddleware = setContext(async (operation) => {
        return {
          headers: {
            authorization: `Bearer ${await getToken()}` || null,
          },
        };
      });
    
      const link = ApolloLink.from([authMiddleware]);
      const httpLink = createHttpLink({ uri: url });
    
      return new ApolloClient({
        link: link.concat(httpLink),
        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
      });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

dont use `operation.setContext`
try to use `setContext` from `@apollo/client/link/context` like this

```
import { setContext } from "@apollo/client/link/context";
```

```
import {
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
  ApolloLink,
} from "@apollo/client";
import { setContext } from "@apollo/client/link/context";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";

const httpLink = createHttpLink();

const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers = {} }) => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("jwt");
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      "X-JWT": token,
    },
  };
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([authLink, httpLink]),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

export default client;
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are not awaiting the promise.
That means it should be `await getToken()`. In order to make this working the ApolloLink function should also be `async`.

This would decrease your performance a little because on every request it would read the token from your `AsyncStore`.
I would do it like that:

```js
import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-client";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import { ApolloLink } from "apollo-link";
import { createHttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";

const cache = new InMemoryCache();

let token
const getToken = async () => {
  if(token) return token;

  token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("jwt");

  return token || null;
};

const httpLink = new createHttpLink({
  uri: ""
});

const authLink = new ApolloLink(async (operation, forward) => {
  operation.setContext({
    headers: {
      "X-JWT": await getToken()
      // this is where I set headers by getToken function
      // If I change function getToken to real token in string type, it works then
    }
  });

  return forward(operation);
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: cache,
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink)
});

export default client;
```

Comment: `new ApolloLink` does not expect a promise, so this is not possible